# Rewrite Rule working fine for https when directly accessed but not when redirected first from http to https

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, aem, dispatcher

Below rule is working fine when domain (https://sitename.com) is accessed. It shows the 'en' page.

1. RewriteRule  ^/$  /content/sitename/us/en.html [PT]

But when http to https rule is introduced first to forcefully redirect all http requests to https via below rule:

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dispatcher/invalidate.cache
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Then the request gets redirected as below:
(http://sitename.com)  gets converted to (https://sitename.com/content/sitename/us/en.html)

Ideally it should be only getting converted w.r.t protocol.
(http://sitename.com) should be converted to (https://sitename.com) & 
 subsequently
https://sitename.com will serve the home page as mentioned in first point, without showing the /content URL in the browser to end user.

Please suggest some pointers here.

Comment: Are you using sling mapping to shorten the URLs and this is rule is only for the specific case of showing the en page as the default homepage?